# bootstrap3 navbar collapsed on jsfiddle but not work on local browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

bootstrap3 navbar collapse worked on jsfiddle as following.

https://jsfiddle.net/wa3he6bn/1/

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>title</title>
    ....
</header>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <nav id="w1" class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w1-collapse"><span
                        class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">Logo</a></div>
            <div id="w1-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="w2" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
                    <li><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Findex">主页</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://docs.mathcrowd.cn" target="_blank">文档</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.php?r=worksheet%2Ffilter">卷库</a></li>
                    <li class="help-link"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.php?r=cart%2Fview"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: jsfiddle]

but when save same html and run locally, it does not collaspe.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use `<head>` instead of `<header>` then Try to use this meta tag in your `<head>` section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

then the navbar will collapse for all screen sizes smaller then 768px as bootstrap's default behaviour.
So to expand it on certain screen break point you can add this class combination
`navbar-expand-*` to the main nav element.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things you should consider in your code.

- **You should put your resources in [`<head>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) not [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)**. There is a major difference between these two, one contains machine-readable information while the other represents introductory content.
- **You need to load `jquery.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`**, because the bootstrap will need to use jQuery.
- You also need to add [`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to your `<head>` to be able to control viewport in all screen sizes.

By honoring these two notes your code should work as expected.

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <!-- 以下为页眉内容 -->
    <nav id="w1" class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w1-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">Logo</a></div>
        <div id="w1-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul id="w2" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
            <li><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Findex">主页</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://docs.mathcrowd.cn" target="_blank">文档</a></li>
            <li><a href="/index.php?r=worksheet%2Ffilter">卷库</a></li>
            <li class="help-link"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/index.php?r=cart%2Fview"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- 结束 -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: js already imported. change header to head makes no difference on local machine.

Comment: @CharlesBao I know the js is imported, but the order of importing it is matter. Just copy and paste the code that I provided in the answer and it should work fine.

Comment: i copy your code snippet to local file and open with chrome. still not collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<head>` tag. and include js files near the end of your page, right before the closing of `</body>` tag.
To save time in the future, please visit bootstrap official docs.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

it's one of the best and well-written documentation.

[image: bootstarp office docs]